# How can I capture xml nodes into hash?

Tags: xml, perl

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Details date="2022-02-09" ver="1">
<VerNum>/14</VerNum>
<Info>
 <model>S22</model>
 <branch name="city_1">
  <stock>10000</stock>
  <def>1</def>
 </branch>
 <branch name="city_2">
  <stock>2000</stock>
  <def>2</def>
 </branch>
 <branch name="city_3">
  <stock>3000</stock>
  <def>0.3</def>
 </branch>
</Info>
</Details>
```

I was trying to access this sample xml file using the code below.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $xml = glob("/ThisPC/C:/ex.xml");
my $parser = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location=>$xml);
foreach my $sec ($parser->findnodes('/Details/Info')) { 
    my $model = $sec->findvalue('./model');
    my $branch = join '',map{$_ ->to_literal; } $sec->findnodes('./branch/@name');
print $branch;
    my $def = join '',map{$_ -> to_literal; } $sec->findnodes('./branch/def'); 
print "\n",$def;
    my $sto = join '',map{$_ -> to_literal ; } $sec -> findnodes('./branch/stock');
print "\n",$sto;
}
```

But I need to store results to hash instead of string. I don't understand how I can do it. Can anyone please help me/ guide me how I can do that please ??

Comment: Updated the xml now, Sorry :)

Comment: ah thank you :)   (that was a simple fix after all :)

Comment: Alright -- what hash?  What do you mean by that -- what are keys, values...?

Comment: Yes, That is what I meant

Comment: A "hash" in Perl is a data structure that has a collection of key-value pairs. Which things in your program should be keys and which should be their values?  (Sorry if it's obvious, I don't see it...)

Comment: The values must be equal to the node values in xml, like (3000 , 2000).
Let me tell the purpose, I need to store results to hash and read that later to output into another xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251749/discussion-between-perlenthusiast-and-zdim).

Comment: I assume that keys for those values are `branch` names then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a demonstration that pulls out the branch information (Itself stored in a hash ref) and adds them all to a hash table:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;
use Data::Dumper;

# Use DATA instead of a separate file to keep the demo self-contained
my $parser = XML::LibXML->load_xml({ IO => *DATA});

# Iterate over each branch, extracting values from child nodes and
# saving in a hash
my %branches;
for my $branch ($parser->findnodes('/Details/Info/branch')) {
    my $name = $branch->getAttribute('name');
    my $stock = $branch->findvalue('stock/text()');
    my $def = $branch->findvalue('def/text()');
    $branches{$name} = { stock => $stock, def => $def };
}

# And pretty-print the hash
print Dumper(\%branches);

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Details date="2022-02-09" ver="1">
<VerNum>/14</VerNum>
<Info>
 <model>S22</model>
 <branch name="city_1">
  <stock>10000</stock>
  <def>1</def>
 </branch>
 <branch name="city_2">
  <stock>2000</stock>
  <def>2</def>
 </branch>
 <branch name="city_3">
  <stock>3000</stock>
  <def>0.3</def>
 </branch>
</Info>
</Details>
```

Output:

```perl
$VAR1 = {
          'city_1' => {
                        'stock' => '10000',
                        'def' => '1'
                      },
          'city_3' => {
                        'stock' => '3000',
                        'def' => '0.3'
                      },
          'city_2' => {
                        'stock' => '2000',
                        'def' => '2'
                      }
        };
```

You can then do whatever you need with that data structure. If you're not familiar with things like hashes of hashrefs in perl, start by reading [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc).

Comment: Thanks Shawn, for the code and also the documentation. It was of immense use. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that branch names need have stock values associated with them, one way

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

use XML::LibXML;

my $file = shift // die "Usage: $0 filename\n";

my $parser = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);

my %branch_stock;

foreach my $sec ($parser->findnodes('/Details/Info')) { 
    for my $branch ($sec->findnodes('./branch')) {

        my $branch_name = $branch->getAttribute('name');
        my $stock_value = $branch->findnodes('./stock')->[0]->textContent;

        #say "$branch_name --> $stock_value";

        $branch_stock{$branch_name} = $stock_value;
    }   
}

say Dumper \%branch_stock;
```

Then if you need to add more information to branch-name keys, instead of associating a single (stock) value with them associate a hashref, which can then carry multiple name-value pairs.

Comment: This code helped me solve the problem too, Thanks a lot @zdim